# javascript change href of all links to onclick=custom_function(pars)

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick

I want to use javascript to make all my links make a post request to their href attribute.

To do so I wrote this piece of code :

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var messaggio = "ciao";                                                  
var url="";     

for(l=0; l<links.length;++l) {
    url = links[l].href;
    links[l].onclick = post(url,messaggio);
    links[l].removeAttribute("href");
}
```

the post function for now is simply

```
function post(url, messaggio) {                                                 
     alert(messaggio + url);
}
```

if I use this code, I get lots of alarms, each containing its url, when loading the page.
If I instead change the code to

```
links[l].onclick = function () { post(url,messaggio); };
```

nothing pops up when loading the page (as it should be) and clicking on a link show an alarm (as it should be) but containing the url of the last link in the page

I guess this is because it creates the same function on the same pointer each time? But I have no idea how to change that
thanks

Comment: You haven't included a definition for the `post` method so there's no way for us to know what's happening.

Comment: so far the code in the post method is commented out and there's only one  alert(url+message). I'll add it to the descriptio

Comment: i just showed you alert(url+message)

Comment: The behavior you are describing (all of them getting the last url) is inconsistent with the code you have shown... The code as presented above will fire 10 alerts in a row at the moment you attempt to attach the click handlers - no clicks are necessary to fire alerts.  Why don't you create a jsfiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Your url var is out of scope

Comment: Mike Edwards you're right, I've again corrected the above description. I've also trying declaring the variable url within the loop but nothing changes. If I use links[l].href in the latter piece of code instead of 'url' it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You having issues with scope. Try this. There is a better way but:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");                          
var messaggio = "ciao";                                                  

for(l=0; l<links.length;++l) {                                        

    links[l].url = links[l].href; 
    links[l].messaggio = messaggio

    links[l].onclick =function (){
        post(this.url,this.messaggio)
    };                                                                        
    links[l].removeAttribute("href");                                    
}
```